# How to get value with (keyup)="getSearch($event, value)" handler until the user stops typing?

Tags: angular, function

now working like this: "a","an","ang","angu","angul","angula", "angular"

How to get value when user already stops typing in input area?

example: get "angular", when user stops typing.

any idea?

Comment: I think what you are asking is not possible. I just checked Google and they make a call for every letter like your code now.

Comment: Event being used is keyup ( asking the control to raise event on each stroke).

Comment: can you try (change)="getSearch($event,value)". it may help

Comment: user2526236, I know, but how to get value when user finishs typing?

Comment: Amit, (change), gets the value when the focus disappears

Comment: How would you even define *when user stops typing*. Would this be after 1 second user has not typed anything, or 5 seconds, 10 seconds, 20 seconds... ? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this (keyup.enter)="getSearch($event,value)" it will call when you press enter after typing.

there is one more way which i think can work in your case. you can use form field observable for this and detect changes & apply function on observable
check this code. modify it according to your need

```
 <form [formGroup]="coolForm">
    <input formControlName="search" placeholder="Search artist">
    </form>
```

component code

```
export class AppComponent {
    searchField: FormControl;
    coolForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private searchService:SearchService, private fb:FormBuilder) {
        this.searchField = new FormControl();
        this.coolForm = fb.group({search: this.searchField});

        this.searchField.valueChanges
          .debounceTime(400)
            .switchMap(term => this.searchService.search(term))
            .subscribe((result) => {
                //////
            });
    }
```

i hope this will help :)